# Como transponer un dataframe en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo la siguiente inquietud

Tengo el siguiente dataframe :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual debo transponer, para ello lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
df = dfs.transpose( )
```

obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como se observa en la imagen, me estan quedando los índices como titulos, y quisiera que mis titulos sean: "DESCRIPTIVA", "Aceite de palma, crudo" , "Aceites vegetales, refinados" y "Margarina y preparaciones"

Me pueden ayudar por favor como mejorar el código, para obtener el resultado deseado.  Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: creo que lo que quieres es hacer un pivot

Comment: Hola @Christian muchas gracias por tu comentario, ensaye esta opción y me servicio.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al comentario de @Christian, explore la opción de pivot_table y me funciono, lo hice de a siguiente manera:

cree una lista con las columnas (ya que son muchas)

```
columnas = dfs.columns.values[1:]
```

[1:] con esto obtengo los valores exceptuando la columna, que requiero transponer, para este caso DESCRIPTIVA

Finalmente ya con la lista, hago lo siguiente:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(dfs, columns='DESCRIPTIVA', values=columnas).reset_index()
```

Y asi logro obtener el dataframe como lo necesito.